# Same size Bitmaps yield byte arrays

Tags: c#

When generating Bitmaps from a WebBrowser's DrawToBitmap() function, while using two images of the same size, why in certain instances, when converting the Bitmap to a byte array, do you have arrays of different sizes?
The function I used:

```
public static byte[] ImageToByte(Image img)
{
    ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
    return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
}
```

From here there is a problem with the images I use.  They are different, I use snapshots of http://www.google.com and http://www.google.co.uk.  They both generate images with a size of {Width = 833 Height = 500}.  However, the sizes of the byte arrays are 20072 and 24368 respectively.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT

Let me add some more information.  The images are turned into BMPs.  I'll attach some more of my janked up C# for you all to understand a bit more.

```
public void captureSnapshot(string url)
{
    this.url = url;
    var thr = new Thread(() =>
    {
        browser = new WebBrowser();
        browser.DocumentCompleted += snapshotEventCompleted;
        browser.Navigate(url);
        Application.Run();
    });

    thr.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thr.Start();
}

public void snapshotEventCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    int pageHeight = browser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height;
    int pageWidth = browser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width;
    snapshot = new Bitmap(pageWidth, pageHeight);
    browser.Size = new Size(pageWidth, pageHeight);
    browser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
    browser.DrawToBitmap(snapshot, new Rectangle(browser.Location.X, browser.Location.Y, pageWidth, pageHeight));
}
```

SOLVED:

So it turns out the function DrawToBitmap is not supported. womp

Comment: Is it a problem? Do you know what format the image is (BMP/PNG/JPG)? If the image is compressed then it could yield different sizes...

Comment: Not sure what you are wondering about. Are you asking why images on google.com and google.co.uk are different? They are different because somebody made them to be different.

Comment: I would be concerned if you had *one* file and converted it into two byte arrays, converted both of them back and the two images were different....

Comment: Do they both have the same pixel format? If one is very basic, is it possible that it is selecting a different pixel format (indexed/pallatized vs 16 bit rgb vs 24 bit rgba etc)?

Comment: They may have different color tables.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the codec used to save the image. If it's PNG or JPG for instance, then the compression might produce outputs of different sizes for images of the same size. That's because large uniform areas are compressed much more efficiently than areas with lots of details.

Answer (score 2):

It's because of something called `Stride` please take a look at this article : [Image Stride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa473780%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[image]

> *Two buffers that contain video frames with equal dimensions can have
>   two different strides. If you process a video image, you must take the
>   stride into account.*

Comment: I don't think that's the reason here; both images were produced the same way, so there's no reason for the stride to be different.

Comment: I've read your answer and it's totally right when we have different codecs but as I've mentioned in my answer , frames from the same video can have different strides although they've produced in the same way ! what I'm trying to say is the way of producing those images is not the only factor for `Stride`

Answer (score 0):

So turns out the function DrawToBitmap  [not supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowserbase.drawtobitmap.aspx).